# JavaScript find element on nested js object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
let object = [{
    "ItemAID" : 1,
    "ItemADesc" : [ {
      "ItemBid" : 11,
      "ItemBDesc" : [ {
        "ItemCid" : 111,
        "ItemCTitle" : "TitleC111",
      }, {
        "ItemCid" :112,
        "ItemCTitle" : "TitleC112",
      } ]
    }]},

    {
        "ItemAID" : 2,
        "ItemADesc" : [ {
          "ItemBid" : 21,
          "ItemBDesc" : [ {
            "ItemCid" : 211,
            "ItemCTitle" : "TitleC211",
          }, {
            "ItemCid" :212,
            "ItemCTitle" : "TitleC212",
          } ]
        }]}]
```

```
console.log(X.find(A => A.ItemADesc.find(B => B.ItemBDesc.find(C=>C.ItemCid === 212)?.ItemCTitle)));
```

I am trying to Find ItemCTitle when ItemCid matches with id.
Above code returns ItemAID:2 object as a whole, instead of returning nested variable value.
Any leads is appreciated.

Comment: Please properly and consistently indent your code. It's hard to read. Also, that's not JSON. It's just a JS object. JSON would be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Array.reduce` you can extract the array of `ItemC` only and can find the item there easily.

```js
let input = [{
  "ItemAID" : 1,
  "ItemADesc" : [ {
    "ItemBid" : 11,
    "ItemBDesc" : [ {
      "ItemCid" : 111,
      "ItemCTitle" : "TitleC111",
    }, {
      "ItemCid" :112,
      "ItemCTitle" : "TitleC112",
    } ]
  }]},

  {
      "ItemAID" : 2,
      "ItemADesc" : [ {
        "ItemBid" : 21,
        "ItemBDesc" : [ {
          "ItemCid" : 211,
          "ItemCTitle" : "TitleC211",
        }, {
          "ItemCid" :212,
          "ItemCTitle" : "TitleC212",
        } ]
      }]}];

const itemC = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (cur['ItemADesc'] && cur['ItemADesc'].length > 0) {
    cur['ItemADesc'].forEach(({ ItemBDesc }) => {
      if (ItemBDesc.length > 0) {
        acc.push(...ItemBDesc);
      }
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []).find(({ ItemCid }) => ItemCid === 211);

console.log(itemC.ItemCTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use library called [d-forest](https://github.com/akarande777/d-forest) for finding deeply nested object.